# How to only install updates from a specific repository?

Tags: apt, pinning

How do I limit the updates that are installed to those from a specific set of repositories? Is this at all possible?

Comment: Do you want to be able to specify repo during runtime, or should be it be more a static thing? The [two](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository/27373#27373) [answers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository/27364#27364) below assume the latter option.

Comment: Ideally it would be during runtime. The static option is sufficient though.

Comment: You heading and the actual help you are requesting are different.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Use Pinning

> Pinning is a process that allows you to remain on a stable release of
> Ubuntu (or any other debian system) while grabbing packages from a
> more recent version. — [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction_to_Pinning)

You can disable automatic updates from certain repositories without entirely removing them via `apt` policies:

To disable automatic updates from repository `repo`, add a file
`/etc/apt/preferences.d/repo` with the following content:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=repo
Pin-Priority: 50
```

Which will give all packages from this repository a lower priority than already installed packages (which have 100).

For more information `man apt_preferences` or check the [Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto).

Comment: It’s a shame the only apt_preferences answer is the last...

Comment: how to find out which version is from which repo?

Comment: @MaxN you would usually find that information by running `apt-cache policy package-name`

Comment: This will not force a repository for not being considered while update. because `release n=repo` will not cache anyone

Answer (score 42):

You can specify a release with `-t` option. As an example, I have added the following repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list` to install Iceweasel latest release:

```
deb http://mozilla.debian.net/ squeeze-backports iceweasel-release
```

As you know there is a same package `iceweasel` in the official Debian repository. If I want install Iceweasel from this specific release I run:

```
apt-get install -t squeeze-backports iceweasel
```

from apt-get manual page:

```
-t, --target-release, --default-release
           This option controls the default input to the policy engine, it creates a default pin at priority 990 using the specified
           release string. This overrides the general settings in /etc/apt/preferences. Specifically pinned packages are not affected by
           the value of this option. In short, this option lets you have simple control over which distribution packages will be retrieved
           from. Some common examples might be -t '2.1*', -t unstable or -t sid. Configuration Item: APT::Default-Release; see also the
           apt_preferences(5) manual page.
```

I think this is a better solution.

**UPDATE**: As @SuB mentioned in the comment, *"`-t` specifies release not repository name. There is no repository name in Ubuntu (unlike RedHat based linux such as RHEL,Fedora,CentOS, ...)".*

Comment: As you see in the `apt-get` manual, `-t` specify release not repository name. There is no repository name in Ubuntu (unlike RedHat based linux such as RHEL,Fedora,CentOS, ...)

Comment: @SuB Yes, you're right! I confused repository name with release!

Comment: `-t xenial` works for a single package. but all it's dependencies will still be fetched from higher packages

Answer (score 14):

### Short Answer

You need to pin the repositories you don't want to install from with a priority less than 100. Which means (from `apt_preference` man page)

> 100 <= P < 500
>   causes a version to be installed unless there is a version available belonging to some other distribution or the installed version is more recent

And to select a repository for pinning, you'd use fields from repositories' `Release` file. Such as `archive`, `label`, `release`, `version` etc. By specifying the values of these fields, you can precisely select a repository and assign your preferred priority to it. Check the [apt_preference](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html) page for more details.

---

### Long Answer

Before proceeding, we need to know some important thing about pinning. Those includes

1. Fields of `Release` files and It's mapping to `apt-cache policy` output
2. Format of apt preference files
3. Using `Release` files fields to set priority

#### 1. Fields of `Release` file and `apt-cache policy` output

From [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat#A.22Release.22_files) article

- Description
- Label
- Origin
- Version
- Suite
- Codename
- Components
- Architectures

You would see output from `apt-cache policy` like these

```
 500 http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/ubuntu/archive xenial/main amd64 Packages
 release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
```

The values in these lines comes from `Release` files.

- **Description** sets the description for a repository. This is not shown in `apt-cache policy` output
- **Label** it is the label of the repository. Many repositories have empty labels. It's shown in `l=<label>` in the output.
- **Origin** this tells about the origin of the repository. Official Ubuntu repository has `Ubuntu` as the value. Shown as `o=` in the output
- **Version** is the version of a distribution. It's 16.04 for Xenial. Shown as `v=` in the output
- **Suite** is same as **Archive**. From debian wiki it's is *The name of the distribution of Debian the packages in this directory belong to (or are designed for), i.e. stable, testing or unstable.*. For Ubuntu, these are `release-updates`, `release-security` etc. For example, `xenial-updates`, `xenial-security`. It's shown in the output as `a=xenial`, `a=xenial-security`. PPAs use just the release name for this, that's why it won't help much in Pinning.
- **Component** tells about the licencing thing. It's `main`, `multiverse`, `restricted`, `universe` in Ubuntu. In the output it's shown as `c=main` or `c=restricted` etc. Most PPAs use `main` for this field, thus it doesn't help in pinning much either.
- **Architecture** is about the OS architecture. Shown as `b=i386` or `b=amd64` in the output
- **Codename** is the release name of the distribution. For 16.04 it is `xenial`. For 14.04 it is `trusty`. Shown in `apt-cache policy` output as `n=xenial` or `n=trusty`. It's same for all repositories for a single distribution usually. That's why it doesn't help in pinning much.

The other line in `apt-cache policy` output starting with `origin` tells the Internet origin of the repository. It also can be used in pinning. But should not be mixed with `Release` files `Origin` field. Those are different.

We'll use these values to pin a repository.

So, how do we use pinning<sup>1</sup> to restrict repository?

There are several ways to control pinning and only a small-subset is effective for Ubuntu. A details explanation is beyond the scope of the answer though. Please refer to [`apt_preference` man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html) for this.

#### 2. Pin file format

Pin or apt preference files reside in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` folder. Each pinning contain three lines.

- First line starts with `Package:` and a comma-seperated package names follow. Regular expressions and globs are allowed
- Second line starts with `Pin:` and it is used to target a set of packages.

  If we want to pin packages from `xenial` higher than `xenial-updates`, we'll use `release a=xenial`.

  If we want to pin version 5.0, we'll use `version 5.0` here. Glob pattens are allowed.

  Or if we want to pin packages from origin `http://archive.ubuntu.com`, we'll use `origin "archive.ubuntu.com"`. Note, we don't write `http://` protocol there.
- Third line starts with `Pin-Priority:` and it's value is a number. Which signifies the priority of the targeted items above.

#### 3. Using `Release` files fields to set priority

Here is an example

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=xenial
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

In this example, packages from `xenial` archives are given higher priority than `xenial-updates` and `xenial-security`.

After pinning, running an `apt-cache policy nautilus` shows that it indeed has given higher priority to a lower version from `xenial` archive over a higher-versioned from `xenial-updates` archive. Notice the `Candidate:` line.

```
nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1
  Candidate: 1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu4 1001
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

But, If we want to give priority over PPA provided packages too, this won't work. Because PPAs use same archive name `xenial` by default. So, assigning a priority to `a=xenial` will also apply to those packages. For example (after enabled PPA),

```
13:31 $ apt-cache policy nautilus
nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1
  Candidate: 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1 1001
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/budgie-remix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu4 1001
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Now the candidate version is from a PPA. Both packages from `xenial` archive of official Ubuntu repo and the PPA have same priority `1001`, because both of them use same value for `Archive` in Release file. To successfully pin, we need to combine more fields in Pin file.

---

### Some examples

#### Pin a PPA repository

To pin packages from a repository, we need to target it using the information found from `apt-cache policy` command. We just saw that `a=xenial` won't help pin-pointing a repository. We need to use multiple fields together using comma in a preference file to precisely target a repository.

For example, to prevent all packages from `http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/` ppa, we can use

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=xenial,o=LP-PPA-oibaf-graphics-drivers
Pin-Priority: 10
```

Here we are using the codename value as well as `Origin` value of the PPA. (Though codename value is not required here actually). Sometimes repository may miss these value. In those cases, some other techniques should be used. The output of `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-glx` says that it works. It lowered the priority of all packages of this PPA.

```
libgl1-mesa-glx:
  Installed: 12.1~git1608200730.16ef7a~gd~x
  Candidate: 12.1~git1608200730.16ef7a~gd~x
  Version table:
 *** 12.1~git1608200730.16ef7a~gd~x 100
        -10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     11.2.0-1ubuntu2.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     11.2.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

*Ignore the fact that it is Candidate. This happended, because It is already installed in my system*. Check the priority at the right

#### Pin a repository when release info is missing

If we want to pin a repository whose release information is missing, like this one `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04`, we must use other method. Since, no other repository is using that origin, we can safely use `origin` to pin this repository.

```
Package: *
Pin: origin download.opensuse.org
Pin-Priority: 10
```

**Note 1:** This origin is the Internet origin, not the one which specifies Vendor in the Release file.

**Note 2:** `Pin-Priority` number has special meaning. Check [`apt_preference` manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html) for details.

Comment: Pinning is completely useless if the package is newer in the repo you're trying to avoid. That is, most of the time.

Comment: @bviktor How about installing with `sudo apt-get install <package name>=<version>` [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package)

Comment: Man page is `man apt_preferences` with S at the end!

Answer (score 7):

A gui based alternative would be to open software centre and select edit > software sources...

[image: Software Sources with Ubuntu software tab selected]

[image: Software Sources with other software tab selected]

all you need to do is un-tick the repositories you don't want updates from.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

Obvious choice is to modify `/etc/apt/sources.list` and comment out all other repositories, and then run

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get autoclean
```

And then remove comments from `sources.list`. Maybe not the best way, but at least `apt-get` man pages do not specify any way to do that.

On related note, for example Ubuntu distribution upgrade process disables all 3rd party repositories during upgrade (and do not just run some option to exclude those temporarily).

Answer (score 2):

One other GUI option is to just choose the origin in Synaptic package manager.

1. Search for the package name you want to install
2. Click the Origin button
3. Choose the repository you want to install from
4. Choose the packages
5. Apply