# How to only install updates from a specific *file* repository?

Tags: 12.04, apt, repository

I created my own internal repository following the instructions here:
[How to create a local APT repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository)

I added the line `deb file:/usr/local/mydebs/ ./` to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`

How do I specify the `--target-release` if my target release is just `./`?

For example if I added the line

```
deb http://mozilla.debian.net/ squeeze-backports iceweasel-release
```

to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` I would specify it like this

```
apt-get install -t squeeze-backports iceweasel
```

[How to only install updates from a specific repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the version of the Debian-based system you are using - you can find it with:

```
cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION=
```

In Ubuntu 13.10, you get this:

```
VERSION="13.10, Saucy Salamander"
```

So for Ubuntu 13.10, you would need to include the word `saucy`, like this line for one of the main repostories:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
```

You can look at the existing repositories on your system using:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In Ubuntu, you can add software using `sudo add-apt-repository ..`, and then running `sudo apt-get update`. This may not work for outdated systems.

More [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine#Adding_Repositories)

Comment: so if i have a *file* entry (not a url) in my sources.list file, what is the exact syntax I need to do a `apt-get install` from that repository?

Comment: `file:///usr/local/mydebs/` might work...

Comment: you mean like this `sudo apt-get install -t file:///usr/local/mydebs/ php`?  It's throwing an error

Comment: it says `Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'file:///usr/local/mydebs/' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources`

Comment: You could try uploading it... [This](http://textuploader.com/) site seems to allow the uploading of text files *(Read any terms and conditions first, and be careful)*, so you could do that, and then click 'Raw' to view just the plain text file. It will look like [this](http://textuploader.com/1ooq/raw) file *(this might only be available for the next 58 minutes, as I only selected '1 hour'...)* It should work as a sources link then... A more secure way may be required though..