# apt-get install nfs-common specific version

Tags: 14.04, apt

Short question: I have reason to install a specific version of `nfs-common` on a new machine. I want to install `1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1`. I believe that I need to `sudo apt-get install nfs-common`, but I'm not sure how to specify the version. I've tried the obvious of:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nfs-common=1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1
E: Version '1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1' for 'nfs-common' was not found
```

---

Long question: I'm trying to install `nfs-common` over a docker image.  At first attempt, I just did `apt-get install nfs-common`.  This failed, presumably because:

> The problem is that nfs-common has been updated in the backports repo, but portmap has not, and the new nfs-common and old portmap are not compatible. So to install it either disable backports, or use force version to install the previous version of nfs-common.
>
> — Source: [Crunchbang.org: [SOLVED] nfs install failure](https://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=185996#p185996).

OK, I'm happy to force a previous version of `nfs-common`.  This would match another machine that was setup months ago, presumably before the latest version was available.  Going to that machine and running `apt-cache policy nfs-common`, I see it has installed `1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1`.  Looking at [man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/apt-get.8.html) for it and:

1. [How to install specific version of some package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package/428778)
2. [How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version)

I see that I need to do something like `apt-get install nfs-common=1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1`.  However, I cannot figure out the exact syntax.  When I tried the above, I received `E: Version '1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1' for 'nfs-common' was not found`.  I received the same error if I used `1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1.2`, which is the default version that's installed.

Obviously I'm not understanding something about the version specified, and I can't seem to find any examples on the web for installing a specific version of nfs-common (or some component that I can map to installing an old nfs-common).

Any help would be appreciated.

Additional note: I tried following the advice at [Debian User Forums: nfs-common and dpkg errors](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=66134#p417434).  I had to add an `apt-get update`.  However, doing the `apt-get install nfs-common` ended up failing with

```
dpkg: error processing package nfs-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nfs-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: On the machine you reference with the correct version, it looks as though `apt-cache policy` should also output the url associated with the package. Can you verify whether this url is accessible (in the apt sources list??) on the target machine?

Comment: Also, if you have the package itself downloaded on the reference machine, maybe you can just `scp` it over to the target machine and install it manually?

Comment: Although I might be able to fight uphill to get this working, it seems like I should be able to do `apt-get install nfs-common=<default version>`.  It I could get that to work, I could try seeing if I could change the version from 1.2 to 1.1.  But, I can't get that to work either.

That said, regarding your specific suggestion, I see `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages`.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure what to do with that information.  I'm used to the basic usages of apt-get only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is correct way to fix name resolution from Docker container?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162163/what-is-correct-way-to-fix-name-resolution-from-docker-container)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/nfs-common/1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1) you can download the package in .deb . Another solution is to install through apt-get the closest lower version, which is available, ie. [1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/nfs-common/1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1) if that would do.

EDIT 1

It installs easily too, at least from 1:1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1 up in case it doesn't.

[image]

EDIT 2

But you need to check yourself if it works alright. You will anyhow :-).

Comment: `sudo dpkg -i /tmp/nfs-common_1.2.8-6ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb` returned:

```dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nfs-common:
 nfs-common depends on libgssglue1; however:
  Package libgssglue1 is not installed.
 nfs-common depends on libnfsidmap2; however:
  Package libnfsidmap2 is not installed.
 nfs-common depends on libtirpc1; however:
  Package libtirpc1 is not installed.
 nfs-common depends on rpcbind (>= 0.2.0-6ubuntu1); however:
  Package rpcbind is not installed.```  Trying to install libgssglue1 gave me further errors.

Comment: this may seem stupid, but can you just double-click the file in GUI?

Comment: or: sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: if still in trouble, go over this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: sorry, i might have flown off a bit. take a look at this one if you got stuck in my second comment http://superuser.com/questions/196864/how-to-install-local-deb-packages-with-apt-get

Comment: And i just noticed you're working on docker. Sorry, but I don't know this context, and you need to take this into account.