# Install an older stdlibc++

Tags: gcc

I use Ubuntu 16.04, and I installed GCC. So I get the version 5.4.

I now want to use GCC 4.9.3. I installed it, but my system doesn't retrieve the matching stdlibc++ (6.0.20). It still has only one version, the 6.0.21, matching to the newest GCC.

How could I install release 6.0.20 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package/428778

Comment: The problem is it seems there isn't any specific package for stdlibc++.