# How to instal apache2 version 2.4.25 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache2

I just used 
`apt-get install apache2=apache2_2.4.25` and I got the error "Version not found".
 So, how can I install that ?

Comment: According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428772/how-to-install-specific-version-of-some-package/428778), the correct syntax is `apt-get install apache2=2_2.4.25`

Comment: Version 2_2.4.25 for apache2 was not found

Comment: It's because this version is not available to 14.04, as we can see [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=apache2). Can [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103320/install-packages-from-newer-release-without-building-apt-pinning) solve your problem?