# how to install python 3.5 on 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apt, python

```
sudo apt-get install python 3.5.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libghc-blaze-svg-dev-0.3.5-84036:i386' for regex '3.5.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-blaze-svg-prof-0.3.5-84036:i386' for regex '3.5.8'
Note, selecting 'libghc-blaze-svg-dev:i386' instead of 'libghc-blaze-svg-dev-0.3.5-84036:i386'
Note, selecting 'libghc-blaze-svg-prof:i386' instead of 'libghc-blaze-svg-prof-0.3.5-84036:i386'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dkms : Breaks: shim-signed (< 1.33.1~16.04.4) but 1.12+0.8-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libghc-blaze-svg-dev:i386 : Depends: libghc-base-dev-4.8.2.0-a3ce8:i386
                             Depends: libghc-blaze-markup-dev-0.7.0.3-608bf:i386
                             Depends: libghc-mtl-dev-2.2.1-05005:i386
 libghc-blaze-svg-prof:i386 : Depends: libghc-base-prof-4.8.2.0-a3ce8:i386
                              Depends: libghc-blaze-markup-prof-0.7.0.3-608bf:i386
                              Depends: libghc-mtl-prof-2.2.1-05005:i386
```

Comment: Please can you add more info about problem,  and[edit] your question.

Comment: take note: it is safer to leave Ubuntu's default Python version unchanged. instead, you could install a specific Python version within a virtual environment.

Comment: If you change default python to 3, you will ruin the whole system.

Comment: my version showing 2.7. I am not looking for upgrading python version. I need python 3.5 .Suggest a way to install python 3.5.8 alongside 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3.5 is installed on Ubuntu 16.04 by default.

Please check `python3.5 --version` in a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You do not provide the version number just as argument. This causes `apt-get install` to look for packages matching "3.5.8". If you want a specific package version check out https://askubuntu.com/a/428778/756449