# Downgrade from PHP 5.6 to 5.5

Tags: package-management, php, downgrade

I need to downgrade my PHP from 5.6 to 5.5

Here is what I've done so far

```
sudo aptitude purge `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php5
```

Then I tried

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install php5=5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1
```

This is what I get when I run `apt-cache policy php5`

```
php5:
  Installé : (aucun)
  Candidat : 5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.2
 Table de version :
     5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.2 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

No matter what I do, PHP 5.6 is installed. I even tried with Synaptic, without success.

Any idea ?

Comment: What's the actual output when you run `sudo apt-get install php5=5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1`?

Comment: The same output as a normal installation of PHP. Like `unpacking of php5-common (5.6.4+dfsg-4ubuntu6.2) ...`

Answer (score 0):

The PPA packages have a `>=` dependency relationship for many packages:

```
Package: php5
Version: 5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1
Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1~) | libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1~) | php5-cgi (>= 5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1~) | php5-fpm (>= 5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1~), php5-common (>= 5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1~)
```

So, if you want to install a specific version of all of them, you'll likely have to specify individual packages with the version specified:

```
sudo apt-get install {php5,libapache2-mod-php5,php5-common}=5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1
```

Or use [pinning](https://askubuntu.com/a/163958/158442) so that the PPA has a higher priority than the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I tried the command you gave me, but I get errors `E: The version « 5.5.26+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1~ » of « php5 » could not be found`. It seems overcomplicated. For the pinning, its seems more adapted to a situation where you want to upgrade from a stable release than downgrade to older packages. Anyway, thank you for your help

Comment: @Hakim the trailing `~` was a copy paste error. Try without it.

Comment: Yes, that's better, but there are still a lot of conflicts, due to dependencies, like `libapache2-mod-php5 (< 5.6.4+dfsg-3~)`. Isn't there a way to specify which version of PHP we want to install, and it would get the dependencies it needs ?

Comment: @Hakim It's in the works, but not right now, it seems. You could try building up from `php5-common` and installing each additional package individually to see where things go wrong.

Comment: thanks, i'll try that. If I can't get it to work, i'll try to mount a vagrant image, it might be simpler. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Hakim Try installing the debug package (`php5-dbg`). It depends on exact versions (`=`, not `>=`).