# Install package from a specific distribution with private apt repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

So I'm hosting a private `apt` repository.

The hierarchy looks like this:

```
├── stable
│   ├── main
│   │   └── binary-all
│   │       ├── Packages
│   │       └── mypackage_2.3.1_all.deb
│   ├── Release
│   └── Release.gpg
└── unstable
    ├── main
    │   └── binary-all
    │       ├── Packages
    │       └── mypackage_2.3.2_all.deb
    ├── rc
    │   └── binary-all
    │       ├── Packages
    │       └── mypackage_2.3.2_all.deb
    ├── Release
    └── Release.gpg
```

My source file looks like this:

```
deb [arch=all] https://user:pass@my.apt-server.com/ stable main
deb [arch=all] https://user:pass@my.apt-server.com/ unstable main rc
```

`apt-cache policy mypackage`

```
mypackage:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.3.2
  Version table:
     2.3.2 500
        500 https://my.apt-server.com unstable/main all Packages
        500 https://my.apt-server.com unstable/rc all Packages
     2.3.1 500
        500 https://my.apt-server.com stable/main all Packages
```

`stable` release file content (without the hashes):

```
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 09:29:19 UTC
MD5Sum:
                 0 Release
               707 main/binary-all/Packages
SHA1:
                 0 Release
               707 main/binary-all/Packages
SHA256:
                 0 Release
               707 main/binary-all/Packages
SHA512:
                 0 Release
               707 main/binary-all/Packages
```

`unstable` release file content (without the hashes):

```
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 09:29:27 UTC
MD5Sum:
                 0 Release
               709 main/binary-all/Packages
               705 rc/binary-all/Packages
SHA1:
                 0 Release
               709 main/binary-all/Packages
               705 rc/binary-all/Packages
SHA256:
                 0 Release
               709 main/binary-all/Packages
               705 rc/binary-all/Packages
SHA512:
                 0 Release
               709 main/binary-all/Packages
               705 rc/binary-all/Packages
```

The problem is, when I try to install from `stable` by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install -t stable mypackage
```

it still installs the latest package from `unstable/main`

```
mypackage_2.3.2_all.deb
```

and not the package from `stable/main`

```
mypackage_2.3.1_all.deb
```

I also tried pinning ([from this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository)) by creating a file under `/etc/apt/preferences.d` with:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=unstable
Pin-Priority: 50
```

but still a higher version from `unstable` is installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 2.3.2 is higher than 2.3.1, and you don't define an apt policy anywhere on your computer for which repository is higher priority than the other.  Without a priority policy defined it will use whichever is the higher version number. (I am on mobile but will write an answer when I am at a computer, if nobody else does)

Comment: @ThomasWard but i thought `-t` option sets a high priority. (apt-get manual) "it creates a default pin at priority 990"

Comment: If you look at the `apt-cache policy` output it directly contradicts the manual.  While it may be true it will *not* respect that for updates and upgrade processes unless you update the pinning priorities to specify specific origin repos and such are a low priority.  I still don't have a computer right now to write up an answer though.

Comment: What's the name of your file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d`?

Comment: @fkraiem, I tried with `unstable` and `repo`

Comment: @Urban48 Both should work... What are the contents of your `Release` files? (Just the headers,  the MD5 sums are not important here.)

Comment: @fkraiem, i updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Release` files should contain a `Codename` header to allow pinning by release name. From `man apt_preferences`:

```
The Release file is normally found in the directory .../dists/dist-name: for
example, .../dists/stable/Release, or .../dists/wheezy/Release. It consists of a
single multi-line record which applies to all of the packages in the directory
tree below its parent. Unlike the Packages file, nearly all of the lines in a
Release file are relevant for setting APT priorities:

[...]

the Codename: line
    names the codename to which all the packages in the directory tree belong.
    For example, the line "Codename: jessie" specifies that all of the packages
    in the directory tree below the parent of the Release file belong to a
    version named jessie. Specifying this value in the APT preferences file would
    require the line:

        Pin: release n=jessie
```

See for reference [the `Release` file of the official Xenial repository](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/Release).

Comment: it worked, i created a config files for unstable and stable for  with a content: `APT::FTPArchive::Release {
Codename "stable";
Components "main";
};` (and Codename "unstable" for the unstable config), and ran `apt-ftparchive` with `-c` to generate the `Release` file with the Codename. after that `apt-get install -t stable ...` worked