# How do I freeze my ppa to the current installed versions?

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, ppa

I have two `ppa` added to my Ubuntu 16.04 installation and would like to freeze the current release that I have thoroughly tested.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot 
add-apt-repository ppa:freeradius/stable-3.0
```

Is there any way to freeze the current version, so that future unattended upgrades don't get the latest which may break the production system?

This is how I have setup my unattended upgrades.

```
sed -r \
-e 's|^//Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";$|Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";|' \
-e 's|^//Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "root";$|Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "root";|' \
-e 's|^//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";$|Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";|' \
-e 's|^//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "false";|Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";|' \
-e 's|^//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";$|Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "03:00";|' \
-i /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades

echo 'APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic

service unattended-upgrades restart
```

Ideally, I could test this first on a test system, and when I'm sure that it all works, I could unfreeze the ppa on production to upgrade to the latest and then freeze it again.

Is this possible?

Comment: See [How to only install updates from a specific repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27362/how-to-only-install-updates-from-a-specific-repository) and [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Comment: What makes you think the default for unattended-upgrades upgrades from ppa's in the first place?

Comment: This is a good question @doug. Was I mistaken in my assumption earlier? Because if unattended upgrades don't get the latest from PPA, then I'm safe enough to keep it as it is.  As I can exercise control. Kindly confirm, if this is the case.

Comment: Can confirm that unattended-upgrades will Not upgrade ppa packages. You can check yourself with `sudo unattended-upgrade --dry-run -d`